# How can I change user permissions for sending messages for all channels?

Tags: discord, discord.js

How can I change user permissions for sending messages for all channels?
I want to block user sending messages to all channels by discord.js.

I try this in code:

```js
let member = message.mentions.members.first()
member.updateOverwrite(client.guild.roles.member, { SEND_MESSAGES: false });
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything? Please provide your current code.

Comment: I try this: member.updateOverwrite(client.guild.roles.member, { SEND_MESSAGES: false }); in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the channels in a particular guild, then modify the permissions for a particular user.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.mentions.members.array().length === 0) return message.reply('No user was mentioned.');

  message.guild.channels.cache.each(channel => {
    channel.overwritePermissions([{
      id: message.mentions.members.first().id, // user ID
      deny: 'SEND_MESSAGES'
    }]).catch(err => console.error(err));
  });
});
```

If you want to only edit the permissions on certain channels, you can use this:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.mentions.members.array().length === 0) return message.reply('No user was mentioned.');

  [/* channel IDs */].forEach(channel => {
    message.guild.channels.cache.get(channel).overwritePermissions([{
        id: message.mentions.members.first().id, // user ID
        deny: 'SEND_MESSAGES'
      }]).catch(err => console.error(err));
    });
  });
});
```

If you want to exclude certain channels from all of them, you can use this:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.mentions.members.array().length === 0) return message.reply('No user was mentioned.');

  message.guild.channels.cache.each(channel => {
    if ([/* channel IDs */].includes(channel.id) return;

    channel.overwritePermissions([{
      id: message.mentions.members.first().id, // user ID
      deny: 'SEND_MESSAGES'
    }]).catch(err => console.error(err));
  });
});
```

**References:**

- [`GuildChannel.overwritePermissions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218946/discussion-on-answer-by-daemon-beast-how-can-i-change-user-permissions-for-sendi).